# Make Babel transpile a group of files independently without "Couldn't find intersection" error

Tags: babeljs

I have a set of Javascript files in `src` directory. These files are completely independent from one another, i.e. nothing requires anything, they are not modules and intended to be used old-fashinally in different html files in `<script>` tags. I have set up babel using package.json (name, version, description etc omitted):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir ./ --source-maps"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "babel-preset-minify"
    ],
    "comments": false
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.2"
  }
}
```

When two certain js files are put in `src` directory, Babel fails to build, producing an error:

```
Error: D:\temp\babel\src\some_script.js: Couldn't find intersection
    at NodePath.getDeepestCommonAncestorFrom (D:\temp\babel\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\ancestry.js:113:11)
    at getSegmentedSubPaths (D:\temp\babel\node_modules\babel-plugin-minify-builtins\lib\index.js:244:14)
    at BuiltInReplacer.replace (D:\temp\babel\node_modules\babel-plugin-minify-builtins\lib\index.js:92:31)
    at PluginPass.exit (D:\temp\babel\node_modules\babel-plugin-minify-builtins\lib\index.js:205:27)
    at newFn (D:\temp\babel\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:143:21)
    at NodePath._call (D:\temp\babel\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:45:20)
    at NodePath.call (D:\temp\babel\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:35:17)
    at NodePath.visit (D:\temp\babel\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:88:8)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (D:\temp\babel\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:86:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (D:\temp\babel\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:65:19) {
  code: 'BABEL_TRANSFORM_ERROR'
}
```

This error does not occur if I delete any one of those files and `npm run build` again, it also doesn't occur every time when there's more than one file inside the `src` directory, it only occurs for this particular pair of files. From which it can be assumed that the files are not transpiled independently and Babel somehow analyzes the content of the files, looking for "intersections" or whatever — a behavior that I never asked for. How to ask Babel to stop doing that, if possible?